Order of await execution makes no sense in node
I wanted to understand at which point an async js function was appended to the event loop and when it was being immediately executed:
async function test2(){
    console.log('3 test2 is being executed');
}
async function test(){
    console.log('2 test is being executed');

    await test2();
    console.log('4 test 2 was awaited');
}

console.log('1 test is about to be called');
test();
console.log('5 test was called');

Originally, I assumed that no matter if a function had any actual async functions happneing (setTimeout, fetch, loadFile, etc), the function would always be appended to the event loop if it was declared async.
So by that logic expected the order of console logs like this:
1 test is about to be called
5 test was called
2 test is being executed
3 test2 is being executed
4 test 2 was awaited

So I assumed, async function that don't have any actual real async functions in them always get executed immediately, leading to this order:
1 test is about to be called
2 test is being executed
3 test2 is being executed
4 test 2 was awaited
5 test was called

But instead I get this:
1 test is about to be called
2 test is being executed
3 test2 is being executed
5 test was called
4 test 2 was awaited

This means the order of execution is:
test is called
test is being immediately executed (despite being marked async)
test2 is being immediately executed (same as test)
after test2 is being run, control is returned to line 14 (which means the event loop must have done something after all)
finally, test reports that test2 was executed.
Can somebody explain this to me? How can it be that async functions sometimes get thrown onto the event loop and sometimes not? I this predictable and when?
Also if you remove the await, the order is 1 2 3 4 5.
I'd just like to understand what's the logic here.
EDIT:
If the await keyword is the linchpin, why does this result in the same execution order?
async function test2(){
    console.log('3 test2 is being executed');
}
async function test(){
    console.log('2 test is being executed');

    await test2();
    console.log('4 test 2 was awaited');
}

console.log('1 test is about to be called');
let a=async ()=>{
    await test();
}
a();
console.log('5 test was called');


1 test is about to be called
2 test is being executed
3 test2 is being executed
5 test was called
4 test 2 was awaited


Asynchronousness is introduced into the program exeuction not by the async keyword but by the await keyword. Hence, #4 is logged asynchronously whereas #1, #2, #3 and #5 are logged synchronously, in that order. If would be different if you said await test(); console.log(5);.

Functions are not "thrown onto the event loop". A call into a function is always synchronous and immediate, async or not. In the case of test2(), it contains no asynchronous operations, so it returns immediately. A Promise will be constructed if it is called with await.

"A Promise will be constructed if it is called with await." - But an async function always returns a promise: (async function (){})() instanceof Promise gives true.

So, in order 1, you call immediately test ⇒ 2. Then test calls immediately test2 and promise to continue with the rest of its code later (that is "thrown onto the event loop"), test2 displays 3. test2 is over. So is 1st part of test (what follows the await line is a promise to continue code of test once test2 will be over). So test returns. Main function shows 5. And this execution is over. Now, the promise are fullfilled. That is the promise to continue test since test2 has finished. That promise what to display 4, which is fulfilled now.

@HeikoTheißen Yeah. A promise to do nothing (but call whatever is in then).

For your edit: why it shouldn't. Let's replay: 1. Then call a(). a calls test and promise to continue the rest of its code (nothing) later. test displays 2. Calls test2 and promise to execute rest of its code later. test2 displays 3 and returns. test is over (the rest is a promise). a is over (the, empty, rest is a promise). So back to main function. That displays 5. Now, time to fulfilled promises. a promised to do nothing. And does nothing. Then, next promise is the one of test, that promised to display 4 and does so.

@HeikoTheißen yes you're right; what I meant was that the Promise makes a difference when the function is called with await, because that returned Promise isn't being ignored as with the "plain" call in the code posted.

I think what you had in mind to demostrate a "contradiction" was rather to put "1" and "5" into a (obviously that was the spirit of your edit: make the "main" function an async function that awaits test). If you had done so (a = async ()=>{ console.log(1); await test(); console.log(5);}), there you would have got your "1 2 3 4 5"

"EDIT: If the await keyword is the linchpin, why does this result in the same execution order?": Adding to your question more questions based on comments, makes it feel like a conversation, where the next set of comments leads to yet another added scenario in your question, ...etc. Could you stick to one question?

An async function always executes synchronously till the first await. Execution continues when the awaited Promise settles. An async function always returns a Promise, even if there is no await inside it. Even if a Promise is resolve(…)d synchronously, its settlement is always deferred to a job.
In both examples the asynchronous events are the settlements of the implicit Promises created by returning from test2 and test.
